# How to forward request from apache web server module to application server

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, proxypass, apache-modules

I should be able to intercept the request using apache modules and after that I should be able to forward that request to application server.

I wrote one module in apache web server, that module will intercept the requests and sending the response.

When I try only with apache module using following configuration it is working fine.

```
<Location "/test.html">
SetHandler my_module
</Location>
```

When I try only with ProxyPass configuration as below in that case also it is working fine.

```
<Location "/test.html">
ProxyPass   "http://192.168.124.1:8080/test/myservlet"
</Location>
```

But, if I want both functionalities in that case it is not working. i.e initially I should be able to intercept the request and after that I should be able to forward that request to application server. 
Can someone please suggest me the approach for this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return DECLINED from your ap_hook_handler() function, or use a different "hook" such as "ap_hook_fixups" which allows more than 1 module to take action.